# CMake variable_watch doesn't show modification of a variable PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE

Tags: c++, cmake

I have invalid value of `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` variable set by `FindPkgConfig.cmake`, so I wanted to check the reason. I've added `variable_watch(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)` for this purpose. The output is following:

```
(...)
CMake Debug Log at /home/my/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:27 (if):
  Variable "PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with value
  "aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/_deps/domedependency/CMakeLists.txt:11 (include)


CMake Debug Log at /home/my/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:30 (find_program):
  Variable "PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with value
  "aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/_deps/domedependency/CMakeLists.txt:11 (include)


CMake Debug Log at /home/my/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:33 (if):
  Variable "PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE" was accessed using READ_ACCESS with value
  "/home/my/Projects/zzz/aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/_deps/domedependency/CMakeLists.txt:11 (include)

(...)
```

So the variable has changed without any WRITE_ACCESS. How is it possible?

What is more, the new variable value is wrong - CMake somehow generated wrong path by concatenating proper executable name with my project's root directory. I think it might be a bug in `FindPkgConfig.cmake`.

Comment: `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` is a CACHE variable. So it is stored between CMake invocations. You need to clear CMake cache (remove build directory or remove just `CMakeCachek.txt` file in it) for observe the variable's assignment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the output is from the first cmake invocation, `CMakeCache.txt` doesn't exist. But I don't think it does matter here - look at the difference between 2nd and 3rd output log section. The variable changes its value in between, during script execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, [variable_watch](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) doesn't track accesses to the CACHE variables. And variable `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` is actually a CACHE one.

However, reading a variable in CMake always uses **non-cache version** of the variable: the non-cache version is created upon the first variable dereference and is set equal to the cache version. More about that can be read in the documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables.

That is, `variable_watch` could be still useful for observe CACHE variables: one may assume that variable is written between two reads which contains different values. In you case, the variable is written between lines

```
/home/my/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:30
/home/my/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:33
```

when (non-cache) variable changes value from `aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config` to `/home/my/Projects/zzz/aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config`.

---

With given script [FindPkgConfig.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.16.1/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake) you may guess where the variable is set.

```
find_program(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE NAMES pkg-config DOC "pkg-config executable")
```

This command is implied to search for executable named `pkg-config`, so it cannot find `/home/my/Projects/zzz/aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config`, which has other base name of the executable. The only reason for such value: the **variable is set in the command line**.

It seems you pass parameter `-DPKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config` to `cmake` invocation. This would explain why `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` has been evaluated to that value before `find_program`.

And this would explain the new value too: `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` should be an **absolute path** to the corresponded executable. So CMake interprets your input - `aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config` - as **relative path** and transforms it to **absolute** one - `/home/my/Projects/zzz/aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config`. This is documented transformation: see description of `-D` option in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/manual/cmake.1.html#options). But this transformation is allowed only for `PATH` or `FILEPATH` types of CACHE variables, that is why the transformation has been delayed until `find_program` call, which defines type of the variable.

So, if you want to set value to variable `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE`, you need to set **absolute path**, not just a name of the executable.

Comment: You are right, the variable is set in the command line. I have also tried to set it in my toolchain file, passed with `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` but it didn't work. Namely, it was just simple `set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config)`. Can you guess why it didn't work? Anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Once again, the `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` should contain **absolute path**, so value `aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config` is simply invalid for it. If you want to ask CMake to find the executable, use `find_program` command. (This way is suitable for the toolchain only, with `-D` option you cannot ask CMake to search anything).

Comment: @OK, the 2 lines in cmake toolchain file solved my problem: `set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE_NAME aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config)` 
`find_program(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE ${PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE_NAME})`

Thanks for your help