# Debug cmake, where is variable defined?

Tags: cmake

I have very complex CMake project. Where variables are often defined like `set("${scope}_${variable_name}" value..)` or other complex way.

I need to find where a variable is defined, where it obtains a value.

I tried `variable_watch` at the beginning of the cmake, but that only gives me `READ_ACCESS` so I guess that setting the variable is not covered in `variable_watch` mechanics.

I need to find out where that variable is set, but I run out of ideas. Variable watch does not help, search sources fails due to complex variable definitions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406540/cmake-variable-watch-doesnt-show-modification-of-a-variable-pkg-config-executab
This link seems to contain some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add on top of the CMakeLists:

```
macro(set name)
  message(STATUS "defining ${name}")
  _set(${name} ${ARGV})
endmacro()

set(a b)
```

and print `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_*` variables.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds really good. Will test it soon.

Comment: Could not test. As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406540/cmake-variable-watch-doesnt-show-modification-of-a-variable-pkg-config-executab suggested I tried to clear all possible cache. And suddenly it started working.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without modifying the cmake files: Simply use `grep` (or windows equivalent) in combination with running the cmake configuration with the `--trace-expand` option.

Using this option for example

```
message("TGT_TYPE = ${TGT_TYPE}")
```

could result in console output like

```
/some/path/CMakeLists.txt(71):  message(TGT_TYPE = UTILITY )
TGT_TYPE = UTILITY
```

so

```
cmake --trace-expand build_dir | grep -P "[sS][eE][tT]\s*\(\s*VARIABLE_NAME\s"
```

should provide you with the line containing the logic to set `VARIABLE_NAME` in the project you've set up in the directory `build_dir`.